# single and multiple records using Cursor with Stored Proc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have the below scenario

1. Fetch records from Database and then process those records(this is lengthy process)
   .
2. DB has around 20,000 records

I have two options
1. Return cursor using Stored Proc having all the records and then iterate through it and keep on processing single record at a time.
2. Fetch one record at a time using stored proc from Oracle Database and Process it.

I am using Spring JDBC for doing it.

I wanted to know in terms of performance which option is good.

Comment: I think you should choose option 3, use bulk processing in stored procedure, `"The bulk processing features of PL/SQL are designed specifically to reduce the number of context switches required to communicate from the PL/SQL engine to the SQL engine"`. Please refer to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html